# Remove individual Wine packages Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 15.04.

I wanted to install PSpice, but I needed a program that would run .exe; I found out about Wine, and so tried to install it like this:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Everything was working fine, I watched it download and install a TON of packages. However, a screen popped up asking for agreement to Eula software terms. There was no way to accept, so I had to end the process by closing the terminal with the "x" button (which locked up dpkg).

I removed the lock file from `/var/lib/apt/lists` and `/var/cache/apt/archives`, and killed the process that had locked dpkg (am I phrasing that correctly?).

So now, the ship is running smoothly, but I want to remove all of the packages that are associated with Wine.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
```

I got a message saying "wine not installed".

There must be some way to identify all the packages in `/var/cache/apt/archives` that are directly associated with Wine, and subsequently remove them.

I'm relatively new to this, please be EXTRA thorough in your help.

Comment: You want cleanup after an install, you try to do this with tricky package manager commands... no, you aren't "new to this", you have a linuxer soul :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your system runs fine, wine doesn't exist on it any more, so there isn't too many to do. What I understand you actually want an afterparty cleanup after your wine try.

Wine hasn't too many dependent packages and they don't harm too many. In similar cases, if there is a large software system from a lot of packages, there is a common package on which all of them depends. For example, in case of X it is `x11-common`, removing it with `apt-get --purge remove` cleans up your whole system from the X entirely. You can find this by calling some `dpkg -s` on some packages recursively, and see where is this "common denominator".

But in the case of wine it isn't the case, wine depends only on some libs. Your system now works, maybe the recursive removal of `~/.wine` would be useful (here are all of your wine settings, even your virtual `C:`).

`apt-get --purge autoremove` removes all of your packages which were installed as a dependency (thus, not directly by `apt-get install`), and whose original package doesn't exist any more.

`deporphan` is also a useful tool, it finds packages who aren't dependency of anything and seem seamlessly uninstallable.

`dpkg -l|grep wine` shows every package whose name or short description contains the `wine` string, maybe some `wine-common` or similar package does exist yet.

Comment: I ended up installing deborphan, and using it.

Comment: @Rho23 Ok. `deborphan -a` gives a much more package to uninstall, although some of them could be useful. If your question was answered, you can accept it by clicking the pipe icon on the left side. It is a reward to me, and makes clear for other visitors that your question is already answered.

Answer (score 1):

> sudo apt-get remove --autoremove wine-stable wine-stable-amd64

use this command to remove wine completely